# SwiftUI - Not able to render the jsonData

Tags: swift, swiftui, swiftui-list

I am very new to SwiftUi and I am trying to view the json data and I am currently working on retreiving the weather data from the openweathermap.org which is a free api to retrieve current weather. I am getting Error parsing Weather Json message. I am not sure what I am doing wrong!! Any help would be greatly appreciated and I have been stuck on this for a day. I referred many blogs and tutorials on how to use the Published var and ObservableObject I am not able to fix the problem.

```
This is my swift file


struct WeatherData {
    public var Id: Int
    public var main: String
    public var weather: [Weather]
    public var icon: String
}

extension WeatherData: Decodable, Identifiable {
    var id: Int {return Id}
}


struct WeatherView: View {
    @ObservedObject var fetch = FetchWeather()

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            List(fetch.weatherData) {
                wthr in
                VStack(alignment: .leading){
                    Text("\(wthr.id)")
                    Text("\(wthr.weather[0].description)")
                    Text("\(wthr.icon)")
                        .font(.system(size:11))
                        .foregroundColor(Color.gray)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct Weather: Decodable {
    let description: String
}

struct WeatherView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        WeatherView()
    }
}


class FetchWeather: ObservableObject {
    @Published var weatherData = [WeatherData] ()

    init() {
        load()
    }

    func load() {
        let url = URL(string: "https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=London&appid=myapikey")!


        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) {
            (data, response, error) in
            do {
                if let wthData = data {
                    let decodedData = try JSONDecoder().decode([WeatherData].self, from: wthData)
                    DispatchQueue.main.sync {
                        self.weatherData = decodedData
                    }
                }
                else {
                    print("No json Data available")
                }
            }catch {
                print("Error parsing Weather Json")
            }
        }.resume()
    }
}
```

Comment: Most likely your struct is wrong but you are not printing the relevant error but some hardcoded string which is really bad. Change the print statement in the catch to `print(error)`. Then you can google or search here on stackoverflow for more info because this api seems quite popular. [stackoverflow search](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bswift%5D+openweathermap)

Comment: Please **read** the JSON. The root object is clearly not an array. And never `.sync` on the main thread

Comment: what error you are getting ?

Comment: @jawadAli The error is obvious:  *Expected array but found dictionary*

Comment: @JoakimDanielson Thanks so much for responding. I changed to error and I got this message: typeMismatch(Swift.Array<Any>, Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [], debugDescription: "Expected to decode Array<Any> but found a dictionary instead.", underlyingError: nil))

Comment: @jawadAli - Thanks so much for responding to my question. typeMismatch(Swift.Array<Any>, Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [], debugDescription: "Expected to decode Array<Any> but found a dictionary instead.", underlyingError: nil))

Comment: Instead of just posting the error why not try to understand it and the other comments posted to your question?

Answer (score 1):

Try this code. I have signed up to get the api and corrected the Model, ViewModel and View accordingly. I have not added the image loader for icon strings.

```
import SwiftUI

struct Weather: Decodable{
    var description: String
    var icon :String
}

struct MainData: Decodable {
    var temp: Double
    var pressure: Int
    var humidity: Int
    var temp_min: Double
    var temp_max: Double

}

struct WeatherData: Decodable, Identifiable {
    var id: Int
    var main: MainData
    var weather: [Weather]
    var name: String
}

struct WeatherView: View {
    @ObservedObject var fetch = FetchWeather()

    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
            Text("Current Weather").font(.title).padding()
            List(fetch.weatherData) { wthr in
                HStack {
                    VStack(alignment: .leading){
                        Text("\(wthr.name)")
                        Text("\(wthr.weather[0].description)")
                            .font(.system(size:11))
                            .foregroundColor(Color.gray)
                    }
                    Spacer()
                    VStack(alignment: .trailing){
                        Text("\(wthr.main.temp-273.15, specifier: "%.1f") ºC")
                    }
                    Text("\(wthr.weather[0].icon)") // Image from "https://openweathermap.org/img/w/\(wthr.weather[0].icon).png"
                        .foregroundColor(Color.gray)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

class FetchWeather: ObservableObject {
    @Published var weatherData = [WeatherData]()

    private let baseURL = "https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q="
    private let cities = [ "London", "Mumbai", "New+york", "Vatican+City" ]
    private let api = "&appid="+"e44ebeb18c332fff46ab956bb38f9e07"

    init() {
        for city in self.cities {
            self.load(self.baseURL+city+self.api)
        }
    }

    func load(_ urlString: String) {
        if let url = URL(string: urlString) {
            URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in
                do {
                    if let wthData = data {
                        let decodedData = try JSONDecoder().decode(WeatherData.self, from: wthData)
                        DispatchQueue.main.sync {
                            self.weatherData.append(decodedData)
                        }
                    }
                    else {
                        print("No json Data available")
                    }
                } catch let error as NSError{
                    print(error.localizedDescription)
                }
            }.resume()
        } else {
            print("Unable to decode URL")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @amithrampur The api in the code is limited use. Use your own api. Also if this works, please accept the answer. Cheers!

Comment: Yes this code is fine and I will work on improving this for my app. Thankyou so much for checking back

Comment: i do have one question. What if I dont want to set the values for cities and I would want to read it directly from the user.

Comment: @AmithRampur In the practical use case senario, if the user give some data, that need to be stored in permanent storage like CoreData or Google Firebase. For coredata integration, check https://github.com/nikhiljohn10/CoreData-MacOS .

Comment: I was looking to get input from the user through text and use the same input across different views. Like for example the name in the above weather api struct lets say there is a text box for user to enter city name and user enters San Jose, I would want to retrieve weather based on that input user entered. I was wondering how I could do that. Any suggestions would be helpful. I don't want to store in permanent storage

Comment: I would also want to call this view with the city name as input provided from another view. Thanks in advance..